Basic question about equidistributed sequences
True or false:
If $f:[0,1[\to[0,1]$ is bijective, then
$$ \left(\ (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ equidistributed } \implies (f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ equidistributed }  \right) \implies $$
$$(\text{ The closure of the graph of } f(x) \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ is made up of line segments, each one having gradient } \pm 1).$$
My feeling/intuition is that this statement, or something closely related to it, is true, and can be proven by contradiction or by proving the contrapositive. That said, I wouldn't be great at proving this (yet), as my experience with measure theory is limited. Is my intuition correct, or is there a counter-example?
Equidistributed sequence
Almost everywhere

What about $f(x)=x+\frac12$ on $(0,\frac12)$ and $f(x)=x-\frac12$ on $(\frac12,1)$?

@GregMartin I have updated the question/my conjecture.

Let $x_n$ be an equidistributed ordering of the rationals, let $f$ be bijective with $f(x)=x/2$ for $x$ rational, then $f(x_n)$ is clearly not equidistributed.

@Gerry Myerson I don't understand what your comment has to do with my question. Please can you explain.

Sorry, Adam, I thought you were asserting that $x_n$ equidistributed implies $f(x_n)$ equidistributed, but upon closer inspection I see that I overlooked a pair of parentheses in your question.
